# Input won't Let Me Input Anything

Tags: html, css

I have this div that is `absolute-positioned` under a `fixed` div. I then tried to insert a form with an `<input>` in it, and it won't let me input anything.

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #0066CC;
    box-shadow:  0px 10px 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:  0px 10px 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:  0px 10px 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#main_index {
    left: 8%;
    right: 8%;
    width: 85%;
    top: 300px;
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

<div id="navbar"><center><b>NAVBAR</b></center></div>

<div id="main_index">
    <div id="index_login">
        <form action="login" method="post">
            <input type="text" required="required" name="username">
            <br />
            <input type="password" required="required" name="password">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem [is *not* present in the code you've posted](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/8nXkF/). Any JavaScript? Have you got a `readonly` or `disabled` attribute somewhere? If you remove *all* the CSS does the problem remain? Can you post a (minimal/[short, self-contained](http://sscce.org/)) [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, live demo that reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure how the rest of your html looks like but are you sure that the `#navbar` isn't overflowing over your `#main_index` div. Try adding for testing purposes:

```
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
```

on your `#navbar` css style and see what happens.

Comment: That didn't do anything. EDIT: Nevermind. I had the z-index set to -1, which puts it under everything.

Answer (score 1):

I believe at least part of your problem is the center tag has been depriciated.  Use a style sheet with the attribute "align:center;" and apply it to your DIV.

Comment: I was temporarily doing that for testing purposes. It didn't fix anything, though.

Comment: I was able to save your provided code (minus the center tag) into an HTML doc and it would let me enter input.  If your styles aren't in a separate doc remember they need to have the <style> </style> tags around them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try with:

```
#navbar {
width: 100%;
padding: 30px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 2;<----------------------bigger than #main_index
background-color: #0066CC;
box-shadow:  0px 10px 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:  0px 10px 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow:  0px 10px 40px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#main_index {
left: 8%;
right: 8%;
width: 85%;
top: 300px;
z-index: 1;<--------------------- positive
min-height: 100px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```